# MacOS disable auto-run of applications upon log in?

Tags: macos, plist, startup, autorun

Is it possible to prevent MacOS application auto-run at login even if it can't be found in the System Preferences under: `Users & Groups → Login Items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable autostart using Microsoft OneDrive Updater as an example

**1. Check applications that you have:**

```
ls -l /Library/LaunchAgents/*.plist
```

output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  523 Feb 17 14:30 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  377 Feb 17 14:30 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.update.agent.plist
```

**2. Open OneDrive Updater:**

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdater.app/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveStandaloneUpdater</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array/>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>86400</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**3. Change `RunAtLoad` to `false`:**

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

**4. Save changes**

**5. ...**

**6. Profit**

<sub>＊Checked at Catalina and Big Sur versions</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked perfectly for me on Big Sur. Nice and thorough on the steps, as well.

Comment: @FibreChips Thank you for feedback and edit suggestions. However I removed OS version from question because it should work on many versions at least staring from Mavericks.